# Creating a middleware controller to handle all requests to Aqueduct in Dart

Tags: logging, dart, routes, middleware, aqueduct

I want to make a logger that will log certain information from every request to the database. I know how to make a controller and I could link it to every route like this:

```
  @override
  Controller get entryPoint {
    final router = Router();

    router
        .route('/register')
        .link(() => LogController(context))
        .link(() => RegisterController(context, authServer));

    router
        .route('/auth/token')
        .link(() => LogController(context))
        .link(() => AuthController(authServer));

    router
        .route('/logout')
        .link(() => LogController(context))
        .link(() => Authorizer.bearer(authServer))
        .link(() => LogoutController(context));

    router
        .route('/words/[:id]')
        .link(() => LogController(context))
        .link(() => Authorizer.bearer(authServer))
        .link(() => WordsController(context));

    return router;
  }
```

As you can see, the `LogController` is repeated for every route.

I would rather just match any route from a single location, log the data, and then let the other controllers handle things as normal. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, return a LogController linked to a Router as your entry point:

```
@override
Controller get entryPoint {
  final router = Router();

  /* configure Router as you are today */

  // Notice the cascade operator... LogController instance is returned
  return LogController(context)..link(() => router);
}
```